# ISO C++ forbids intilization of member maxY

Tags: graph, plot, arduino, arduino-ide

That's a code for using graphs in arduino but i'm getting an error saying 
ISO C++ forbids intilization of member maxY. Can I know why?

```
class Graph 
{
  float maxY = 0;
  float maxX = 0;
  int maxI = 0;
  boolean Dot=true;            
  boolean RightAxis;            
  boolean ErrorFlag=false;      
  boolean ShowMouseLines=true;
```

Comment: Guess what. Because it's not permitted to initialize non-static class members inline.

Answer (score 1):

Because C++ forbids initialisation of instance members in-line like that.

You should initialise them in the constructor or, if they're meant to be class variables (one shared across *all* instances) rather than instance variables, make them static.